Is "required" tooltip on required fields legend required?
Recently the new "required" icon (a red star symbol) was added next to Title, Body, Tags words on Ask New Question page around all SE network. I think it's a good change for site UX. But do we really need this tooltip for legend item itself?



I know it's very very minor issue, but still...

It is consistent where ever that element appears <abbr class="s-required-symbol" title="required">*</abbr>. I'm more concerned about the inconsistent pointer style on that element.

@rene do you mean mouse pointer style?

Yeah, I realized later that you might use a phone/tablet with only touch so you probably wouldn't notice.

@rene actually there's no tooltips (natively) on touchscreens. So screenshot was taken on regular Windows PC with mouse, but the mouse pointer is hidden for some reason (however option to capture mousepointer is enabled), IDK why.
